# Position in developers story missing menu after completing edit

Tags: bug, developer-story

After modifying (adding or editing existing) job position the cogwheel
 (used to show context menu containing edit/delete options) is not shown:

---

[image]

---

I have to refresh chrome page (<kbd>F5</kbd>) to see it.

Another little thing is 3 years estimation. Imho it should be pure math unless month are specified (2002 - 2000 = 2 years). I see if someone would enter `2000-2000` you don't want to show 0 years, but 1 year could be very wrong if person worked just a month. I was working ~1.5 years and it shows very wrong 3 years (2 years would be ok).

Comment: I experience the same issue.